# Inner product associated with the Hausdorff distance

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Since each inner product uniquely induces a norm, which in turn induces a metric, I wonder whether we can backward and seek the functional form of the inner product that induces the Hausdorff distance.

Comment: The answer is probably no. In fact, the criterion of a valid metric is very weak, while an inner product entails much more conditions such as the ability to define orthogonality. The Hausdorff metric does not seem to even permit the definition of a valid norm, which can be used following the parallelogram law to define an inner product.

Comment: As a basic requirement, a norm requires a vector space structure. There isn't naturally a vector space structure on the collection of subsets of space.

Comment: @Zorngo Thanks for pointing that out!